# SharePoint Permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a user who i have added to site owners group. Still the user has only read permissions to the site.. He can only see 'View All Site content; option under Site Actions. This is really weird.. Anybody has an idea about this ? Please help !

Answer (score 1):

please check the user has the correct permission! he could be in the group but could have limmited permission!

you can check the users permission:

> You can check the permission levels for anyone in your organization.
>   Click Check Permissions on the permissions page for the site and then
>   type the name of the person you want to check in the User\Group box.

please follow this guide:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/roadmap-grant-permissions-for-a-site-HA101794118.aspx

check permission:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment..
I checked the user permissions.. It says full control through the owners group..followed by a message 'the following factors also affect the level of access..' then a list which says 'deny' for everything.. Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: sounds like you have to check the policy settings in central admin, same situation here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ad8f9591-be8a-4664-bbf7-e39bca58101e/sharepoint-2010-permission-level-full-control-and-explicit-deny?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Answer (score 0):

Does that site's Site Owners group have sufficient permission?  Maybe try creating a new group with either Full Control or Manage Hierarchy under that site, then drop the user in there and see if they can get to the other site actions?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I checked the user permissions.. It says full control through the owners group..followed by a message 'the following factors also affect the level of access..' then a list which says 'deny' for everything.. Any idea, how to fix this?

Comment: I've seen that before, could this be your issue? [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36588/...](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36588/sharepoint-2010-permission-level-full-control-and-explicit-deny)